# What is the difference between id and _id in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

What is the difference between `_id` and `id` in mongoose? Which is better for referencing?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id):

> Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an id virtual getter by default
>   which returns the documents _id field cast to a string, or in the case
>   of ObjectIds, its hexString.

So, basically, the `id` getter returns a string representation of the document's `_id` (which is added to all MongoDB documents by default and have a default type of `ObjectId`).

Regarding what's better for referencing, that depends entirely on the context (i.e., do you want an `ObjectId` or a `string`). For example, if comparing `id`'s, the string is probably better, as `ObjectId`'s won't pass an equality test unless they are the same instance (regardless of what value they represent).

Comment: please see revised question

Comment: As far as what's better for referencing, that depends entirely on the context (i.e., do you want an `ObjectId` or a `string`). For example, if comparing `id`'s, the string is probably better, as `ObjectId`'s won't pass an equality test unless they are the same instance (regardless of what value they represent).

Comment: @jmar777 The ObjectId does have an `equals` method which can be used for comparison.

Comment: Watch out for nested documents. Mongoose won't assign the `id` virtual to nested objects, even though they have an `_id` field with an ObjectId.

Comment: @EladNava Does that mean if you want one document to reference another, you should assign a custom field the model that references the _id field?

Comment: @AlxVallejo Not necessarily, you just need to read from the `_id` field yourself and convert it from an `ObjectId` to a `string`.

Comment: So in short book.id === string and book._id === ObjectId, just putting this out for future reference :)

Comment: I've spent a lot of time without knowing this. I just used _id.toString() all the time, lol. It's really important to read the documentation...

Comment: The flipside of the 'comparing a string' use case is using aggregate().match() which expects an ObjectId, so `_id` is the prefered, or else generating an ObjectId from a string with `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(string)`