# mongoose object relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a new access token object. In the debugger, I can see that the user._id value is returned correctly. But when assigned to the token user field, the value of token.user._id is undefined and token.user.id is some garbage value. The same behaviour is observed even after saving the token.

```
exports.create = function(user, client, deviceId, done) {
    if (!user) return done(new Error('Failed to create client without user'));
    var token = new AccessToken({
        user: user._id,
        client: client._id,
        deviceId: deviceId
    });
    token.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        return done(null, token);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
var token = new AccessToken({
    user: user._id,
    client: client._id,
    deviceId: deviceId
});
```

You're assigning your user's id to `user` so you can use it with `token.user`.
If you want to access your user's id with `token.user._id` you should do :

```
var token = new AccessToken({
    user: user,
    client: client._id,
    deviceId: deviceId
});
```

but you will have to use [`.populate('user')`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) when querying to access to `token.user._id`

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose you use `.id` to access the `._id` field as a string.
[What is the difference between id and _id in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724272/what-is-the-difference-between-id-and-id-in-mongoose)

Comment: Yes. But my intention is to use _id as a object reference here and not as a string.