# Mongoose - Cast to ObjectId failed, Multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

```
return new SavedMember({
    id: member.id, // ID of the user
    guildId: member.guild.id // ID of the guild
}).save();
```

gives error:

```
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "218459216145285121" at path "_id" for model "member"',    
  name: 'CastError',
  model: Model { member }
```

member.ts

```
const memberSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Types.ObjectId,
    id: String,
    guildId: String,
    xpMessages: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    warnings: { type: Array, default: [] }
});
...
export const SavedMember = model<MemberDocument>('member', memberSchema);
```

Repo: https://github.com/theADAMJR/2pg-dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724272/what-is-the-difference-between-id-and-id-in-mongoose):

*Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an id virtual getter by default which returns the documents _id field cast to a string, or in the case of ObjectIds, its hexString.*

So, when you try to add a new document, the id property refers to _id