# Why does my Array.prototype.find() return undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose

I have a route handler in which I am attempting to find a user's collection of club objects, then find the specific club object using Array.prototype.find().  I have no idea why it is always returning undefined.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
router.get('/club', async (req,res) => {
    try {

        console.log(req.query.club); 
        // 6008d7537ea5c22b61dc616b
        
        const { clubs } = await User.findOne({ spotifyId: req.query.id }).populate('clubs').select('clubs');
        
        console.log(clubs); 
        // [{"_id":"6008d7537ea5c22b61dc616b","name":"asfasfs","description":"sdfasfa","privacy":"private","frequency":"bi-weekly","__v":0},{"_id":"6008ec8026900630c24fd533","name":"asfasfdsasf","description":"asdfasfdsf","privacy":"private","frequency":"monthly","__v":0}]
        
        let club = clubs.find(currentClub => (
           currentClub._id === req.query.club
        ));

        console.log(club)
        // undefined
        
        res.send(club)
    }
    catch {
        return res.status(400).send('No club found with given id')
    }
})
```

Comment: Because you have an array of one element (index 0) and that is an object inside. .... Also, and I like that you comment the data structure, but if that is a string, you need to `JSON.parse()` that to use it.

Comment: Because [Mongoose `._id`s are objects](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/objectid) (even though `console.log` shows it as a string here). An `===` comparison to a string will always fail. You could use [`.id`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724272/what-is-the-difference-between-id-and-id-in-mongoose) instead.

Comment: Why are you using `Array` methods at all? Just `Club.findById`!

Comment: @Bergi I guess my thinking was that I want to verify that the club belongs to the user by getting a list of the user's clubs and then filtering.  Maybe that is not necessary?

Comment: @butthash3030 I'd probably store the owner on the club object then verify that, or try to write a query that does the check in mongodb so that I don't have to load all clubs. But that might be premature optimisation, or I'm too relational-database minded.

Comment: I originally had it set up the first way you mentioned.  I will consider that again. Thank you.  Your original solution works.

Answer (score 1):

**_id** is an *object*

Change your code like this

```
String(currentClub._id) === req.query.club
```

or

```
currentClub._id.toString() === req.query.club
```