# Mongoose id and _id changes the value in response

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, nestjs, class-transformer

**I am getting different ID value in `JSON response` when checking variable as `id` & `_id` in DTO**

**CASE I ( using id as variable )**

***DTO for the response***

```
export class UserDetail {
    
        @Expose( )
        id: string; //HERE ID is used which gives original id as in db
    
        @Expose( )
        name: string;
    
        @IsOptional( )
        @Expose( )
        mobile: string;
   }
```

***Response for this is:***

```
        {
            "id": "6229df5cc32d3aaef32525e0", // Correct id as in db
            "name": "Name1 Title1",
            "mobile": "AB391C339",
        },
        {
            "id": "6229df7bc32d3aaef32525e3", // Correct id as in db
            "name": "Name2 Title2",
            "mobile": "CDE393F339",
        }
```

**CASE II ( using _id as variable )**

***Now changing DTO***

```
export class UserDetail {
        
       @Expose( )
       _id: string; //HERE _id is used which gives different id value from original one and subsequent ids are in incremental fashion
        
       @Expose( )
       name: string;
        
       @IsOptional( )
       @Expose( )
       mobile: string;
  }
```

***Response for this is:***

```
        {
            "_id": "624023c8193f2404f8312ccb", // Not same as present in db
            "name": "Name1 Title1",
            "mobile": "AB391C339"
        },
        {
            "_id": "624023c8193f2404f8312ccc", // Not same as present in db
            "name": "Name2 Title2",
            "mobile": "CDE393F339"
        },
```

***Schema for user is:***

```
@Schema( )
export class User extends Document {

    @Prop( { required: true } )
    name: string;

    @Prop( { required: true } )
    mobile: string;
}
```

***Another Observation:* With the use of `_id` in dto, all the ids in response are in incremental fashion. `eg. cb, cc, cd, ce`
& with only `id` in dto it's showing ids as `original id` in db.**

**`Library & Framework Used: NestJs, Fastify, Mongoose, Class-Transformer`**

Comment: Please share your schemas, so we can understand better what you are trying to query.
Perhaps you have both _id and id in your schema (as Lukasz Piwowar mentioned)

Comment: updated the question with schema

Answer (score 1):

i don't quite understand your question...

you need to give some information about what libraries you are using and what you are actually trying to do.

so far i can only tell you that mongodb uses the `_id` filed as a unique identifier for each record.

the value for this identifier also relies on the time at which it is created ([read more](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/))

some libraries also add a virtual field `id` to each entry which links back to `_id`, this is only done for cosmetic purposes.

each table entry needs such a unique id for indexing and relational data modeling.

i hope this provided at least something useful to you

Comment: Question has been edited.

Comment: Am getting different id value in response, when changing variable from id to _id in dtos.

Comment: having the same issue with the same code structure. @PRABHATSINGHRAJPUT how did you solve it? please let me know.

Comment: Yet to find the solution or reason, so for now to get the work done am using case 1.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you wrote only explanation that came to my mind is that your documents accually contain both fields id and _id, that might happen if someone imported documents directly to database in some wired way. It happened to me once when I imported raw json backup.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the code you shared, there is no such thing as "id" in you schema.

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724272/what-is-the-difference-between-id-and-id-in-mongoose) and see if it helps you figure it out.

Comment: Yes, but changing variable from id to _id in DTO gives different result, also id in DTO gives correct id as present in db ( _id ).