# Query doesn't show id in document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to display a document, but the id field is missing, although it's in the database.

```
Topic.findOne({id: 31}).sort({id: -1}).limit(1)
    .then((topic) => {
      console.log(id); //null
      const newTopic = new Topic({
        id: 32,
        level: level,
        topics: topic,
        phrases: [phrases1, phrases2],
        nouns: [nouns1, nouns2, nouns3],
        verbs: [verbs1, verbs2, verbs3],
        adjectives: [adjectives1, adjectives2, adjectives3],
      });
      newTopic.save();
      res.redirect("/admin/panel")
    });
//console.log output
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("620eb4d998b1747bbe24c672"),
    level: 4,
    topics: 'What is your definition of risk?',
    phrases: [ 'Risk is the...', "Anything that is/isn't..." ],
    nouns: [
      'possibility',
      'change',
      'probability',
      'fear',
      'occurrence',
      'proposition'
    ],
    verbs: [
      'to perceive',
      'to reject',
      'to involve',
      'to ruin',
      'to take',
      'to realize'
    ],
    adjectives: [ 'extraordinary', 'uncertaintly', 'different', 'unfavorable', '' ]
  },
```

As you can see in the image, "id" is in the document, but not shown in the console.

[image]

Comment: `console.log(topic.id);` maybe?

Comment: Cannot read property 'id' of null. That's the answer I get. I don't understand why id is not shown in console, but the rest is.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `id` is a getter of `_id` as a string, that's why you can't find it. Check this, it should answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15724424/4518630

Comment: The problem is I have another collection where id is displayed.

Comment: ```[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62fd0516b96139210c258a10"),
    id: 59,
    level: 1,
    topic: '1',
    phrases: [ '1', '1' ],
    nomen: [ '1', '1', '1' ],
    verb: [ '1', '1', '1' ],
    adjective: [ '1', '1', '1' ],
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Comment: Id is shown in here